# animation block not working

Tags: iphone

im trying to update a uilabel sequentially via animation and as far as i can tell the label never animates it just goes from its default text to [tweets objectAtIndex:2]

```
- (void) statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses
               forRequest:(NSString *) connectionIdentifier
{
    for ( NSDictionary *dict in statuses )
    {
        [tweets addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"text" ]];
    }




        tweetsLabel.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:0];
        [tweetsLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-BoldItalic" size:42]];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.5 
                         animations:^{tweetsLabel.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity;} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             tweetsLabel.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:1];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.5 
                         animations:^{tweetsLabel.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity;} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             tweetsLabel.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:2];

                         }];}]; 



    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want two animations happening on the same view at once, they will cancel each other out so to speak.  You want one animation block that does everything you need.

Comment: how do i get the block to re-fire then?  how do i get my sequential animations?   not really sure i understand what your saying.  since the next animation is in the completion: part of the block

Comment: well i was trying to get the latest three tweets.  if i only do one block i should be able to get 2 out of it. but this doesnt work either 
        
        
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.5 
                         animations:^{tweetsLabel.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity;} completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             tweetsLabel.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:1];
                             
       tweetsLabel.transform =CGAffineTransformIdentity; }];

Comment: sorry didnt realize i didnt except your answer.  thank you for this